# I can't rename a file using the terminal if it came from a parameter

Tags: bash, scripts

I am automating some deployment task with an .sh script but at some point I need to rename a file but it is not working. The file change can be different but the postfix is the same.
Let's have a look at this example so you will understand what is that I exactly need:

```
read folderName
#... at somepoint this scripts creates a file called foldername-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war (I need to rename it)
oldExecutableName ="" + $folderName + "-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" 
newExecutableName ="" + $folderName + ".war"
[[ -f "${newExecutableName}" ]] &&
mv -v ${oldExecutableName}   ${newExecutableName}
```

Example:

Given input `filename`

Desired name for file is: `filename.war`

The text -1.0-SNAPSHOT should be removed from the name of the file

for some reason this is not working, and I think it is because the parameter I am reading from the terminal. Can someboby give me a hand to rename this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
read -p "Enter Filename :- " finalFinalName
remove_extention='-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war'
addExtention='.war'

[[ -f "${finalFinalName}" ]] && # if file exists then rename 
mv -v $finalFinalName   ${finalFinalName%$remove_extention}${addExtention}
```

If there is white space in file then then double quotes the variable eg. `"${var}"`

`${finalFinalName%.*}` this will remove extension

Comment: I made a little mistake in my question. I already have the extension. I need to remove it, that is what I need.

Comment: not an issue.. just small changes required .. `${finalFinalName%.*}`

Comment: I think I am close but is not exactly it. 
Please see the update to my question. I again expressing wrongly. 
I don't want to say extension, what I want to say is ending(not just after the dot).

Comment: Please check now , I have updated..

Comment: @sfrj , are you facing any issue ?